# Absolute file path from selected node in treeview C#

Tags: c#-4.0, filepath

I am making a GUI file mover using Treeview, the only issue I am having is getting the absolute file path.

When I use this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text);

        sourceDir.EnumerateFiles();

        var fileToMovePath = Path.GetFullPath(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
        var pathToMoveToo = textBox2.Text;

        //File.Move(fileToMovePath, pathToMoveToo);
        MessageBox.Show(fileToMovePath);
     }
```

I get this file path:

[image]

Which obviously isn't what I want, as that file is actually stored on my desktop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem and after some trial and error following solution worked for me.

**Replace**

```
var fileToMovePath = path.GetFullPath(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
```

**With**

```
var fileToMovePath = textBox1.Text + "\\" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
```

I think the problem here was with ***path.GetFullPath()***, that it was displaying the path to directory from where program is being executed and not the one we picked.